# How to show correct OS X help file?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a working help file for my OS X program. I edited the .html file and saved it in the .help package. When I run the program in XCODE 5 and call the help file (click on Help>LRotor Help), the changes don't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you deleted the application bundle before you build your project when adding/modifying extra files, that should work

Comment: Bingo! Got it in one.